# How to prompt user for numberic only input?

Tags: android-auto

I'm looking into extending an application to support Android Auto. This would be a POI app helping users find a physical location and would let them communicate via an API call a numbered parking spot that they have parked in once they have arrived.

The problem i'm running into is the input of the parking spot number. I've looked at which templates support the user inputting information (`SearchTemplate` for instance) and that doesn't fit my use-case since it allows alpha-numeric input and is meant to be used for search. Looking at the Phone Dialer app, that has a number pad input available, but i don't see a clear way to a present a UI similar to that. Is there a recommended approach to this or a different UI widget available in the template system that would allow me to achieve my desired behavior?